# Cannot install.packages(qwraps2) in R. What is happening?

Tags: r, package, qwraps2

> install.packages(qwraps2)
> Error in install.packages : object 'qwraps2' not found

This package wont install, I get the above error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `install.packages("qwraps2")` instead.

it will not work without the quotes around package name

Comment: Silly me, that was it. Thanks